# C++ Dereferencing array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 3 dimension array, the third dimension refers to existing arrays:

```
int FrontStep[12]{
90,90,90,90,
35,50,66,81,
115,122,119,115
};


int (*Move[100][4])[12];

Move[0][0] = &FrontStep;
```

Those are co-ordinates for Bezier curves for a quadruped and I wish to extract them back in one piece instead of pieces.

I know how to get a single coordinate:

```
int x = *Move[0][0][0];
```

But what I would like to get is the whole array for, in this case, FrontStep.

```
int M = Move[0][0] ???????
```

What is the syntax for that? I've been studying arrays of arrays in C++ for a while now, and my understanding is still mired in confusion!

Comment: A single coordinate would be `(*Move[i][j])[k]`.

Comment: It would be easier to do `int *Move[100][4]; Move[0][0] = FrontStep;` and `int x = Move[0][0][0]` and `int *M = Move[0][0];`.

Comment: The indexing expression will fail for other indices. You need parentheses, like this: `int x = (*Move[0][0])[0];`. It's a good idea to **name things**, in this case your types, e.g. using `typedef` or C++11 `using`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option #1

```
int (&M)[12] = *Move[0][0];
//   ^         ^
std::cout << M[0];
```

#### Option #2

```
int (*M)[12] = Move[0][0];
//   ^
std::cout << (*M)[0];
//            ^
```